# A links and forms stopped working,

Tags: html

I have a website that was working fine and all links worked but normal mailto links now do not work and a form stopped working. It is in development but its [here](http://breadr.co). I am using git so I can go back to an old version that was working but was just worried and went to stack overflow. Thanks again.

Comment: In what way is it failing?

Comment: When links are clicked nothing happens

Comment: You do realize you need to have a real URL in the form action right? That or none at all and use JS to handle this you have- http://breadr.us8.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post which is not a real url.

Comment: Edit to the above, mailto:links my bad i was looking at your subscribe. Anyways it seems since it has an attached listener of click that you may be preventing the default action so check into that.

Comment: Thanks it was all working until today I didnt really change any code besides css and html idk.

Comment: If you need more hands on support I'm on wizpert.com/christopherbaldwin ok just ping me and I'll come soon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in JS because if you disable it - links will work again. Probably you should start with looking at the error list in the browser console. One of them is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` on http://breadr.co/slick/slick.css resource and another one is JS related.

Comment: CSS won't conflict with JS, though a missing or bad parameter for a JS url will conflict. The only thing i can see is if a e.preventDefault() or return false; are being used that it would conflict with the `mailto:` anchor property.

Comment: @EasyBB i is unknown what kind of js code there is and what went wrong. But yeah best guess is `preventDefault()`

Comment: Looking at his form, the url for action isn't even real so

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix your mail link

```
<a class="nodecf" href="mailto:hello@breadr.co?Subject=Hello" target="_top">Contact</a>
```

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp